# Changing variable for all objects of one class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am new to Python and I run into a problem.
To keep it simple instead of sending you all my code I will generalize it a bit. 
I want to create a class "object" with an x and y coordinate.

```
class Object():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

object_1 = Object(0,0)
object_2 = Object(20, 20)
object_3 = Object(100, 100)
```

I created three objects of class Object(), each with an individual x and y coordinate. Now I want to add e.g. 5 to all three x coordinate without typing it manually. Is there a smarter way to add 5 to all members of this class?
i am sorry in case my question was answered in another post but I could find anything that helps me. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `without typing it manually` ?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar in my code I have a background image. it moves in the opposite direction of the player. now I want to create, lets say 20, obstacles, moving always the same way as the background. How do I avoid typing obstacle_1.x += ... for every obstacle. I hope you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing it individually, do it in group, you could build a static method in the class that adds a value to the `x` of all given objects

```
@staticmethod
def addX(value, *items):
  for item in items:
    item.x += value

# call
Object.addX(5, object_1, object_2, object_3)
```

## [`Code Demo`](https://repl.it/repls/RoastedGreenPlan)

Answer (score 0):

Save all of your obstacles in a list when you create them, something like a group.
You can save them in a list or save them inside another class that they are related to.

Then in each desired move execute a loop over that list, something like this:

```
for obstacle in obstacles:
    obstacle.x += 5
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution for my case.  Heres my class Obstacle `class Obstacle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x
        self.y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)` and I want to create a few objects of this class. E.g. object_1.x = 5 and object_2.x = 20 etc. how do I add 5 to the x values of all objects?